# Share data between base class and Meta class

Tags: python, django, model, metaclass

I have the following django model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    keys = ['filename', 'collection']

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(
                    fields=['filename', 'collection'],
                    name='article_key')
                ]
```

As you can see I've defined the same list ['filename', 'collection'] in both the base class and the Meta class. I would like to define it once. I can't define it in Meta because then I get 'Meta got an unrecognised attribute 'keys'. So I must define it in the base class and access it from Meta. I don't know how to share data between the two. I've tried doing:

```
self.keys
```

in Meta but that gives 'self is not defined'. I've also tried with just 'keys' but that's also not defined. Any tips? Thanks.

**EDIT**
Thank you to Willem for pointing out that I can define keys in Meta if I just call it '_keys'. If I do this, however, the question is then how do I access _keys from the base class? I've tried 'meta._keys' and 'Meta._keys'. Both not defined.

**EDIT 2**
For clarity, the reason that I want 'keys' defined in the base class is that I will (a) be accessing it from properties on the base class, and (b) want to be able to access it from the outside.

Comment: You can add any possible attribute in meta if it starts with an underscore.

Comment: Can't you do `Article.keys` in `Meta`?

Comment: @FiddleStix tried that, Article is not defined....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it before the class, then reference it from both the model class and it' Meta:

```
# making it a tuple since you probably don't want
# it to be mutable
_ARTICLE_KEYS = ('filename', 'collection')

class Article(models.Model):
    # making it an implementation attribute since you
    # probably don't want to be writeable 
    # (hint: provide a read-only property for access)

    _keys = _ARTICLE_KEYS

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(
                    fields=_ARTICLE_KEYS,
                    name='article_key')
                ]
```

But this is still ugly IMHO and very probably unecessary - the model's **methods** should be able to access those values thru `self._meta.contraints[0].fields` or something similar (don't have models with such constraints at hand right now so I can check how this is actually transformed by the models's metaclass but inspecting `self._meta` in your django shell should give you the answer).

Answer (score 0):

The methods of a nested class cannot directly access the instance attributes of the outer class.

So, in your case, If you won't use the `keys` list in the `Article` class, just defined it once in the `Meta` class. Otherwise, you need to defined twice!

Comment: Where have you seen a method in the nested class ? This is an attribute, not a method. Anyway: this is Django ORM code, and the nested `Meta` class is turned by the model metaclass into an `Options` instance (attribute of the model class), so the model's methods class CAN access it thru `self._meta` (or `cls._meta`).

Comment: Yes, you are right that it is an attribute. But in your example, you show access from `outer_class._meta` but the question was about nested_class.outer_class.attr

Because he wanted to use an attribute of outer class inside the nested class.

Comment: What the op wants is to make the same object available in both classes without repeating it. Whether it's defined in one or the other is not important here ;-)